# Servlet Name Mismatch

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on an application which demonstrates the use of Validation

in spring.

I am getting the following errors.

(1)parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/application-config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/application-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

(2) class path resource [spring/application-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

(3)ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Aug 12 11:56:31 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy

(4)LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Aug 12 11:56:31 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy

(5)BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext

```
my src/main/resources/spring contains 

1.application-config.xml
2.mvc-config.xml
3.spring.xml
4.web.xml
```

Should I change the location of these files????

**When I run the project, the url is http://localhost:8080/spring/**

Comment: What you have listed is the directory structure - what is the location in the deployed war file? jar -xvf warname.war

Comment: The location is D:\STSWorkspace\SpringFormValidation\src,

Comment: There will be a target folder under this with a .war file in

Comment: no; it is not there.'

Comment: what should I do now? generate it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can put it in the /WEB-INF but you can change the path with FileSystemXmlApplicationContext when you are creating the ApplicationContext.

```
private static final FileSystemXmlApplicationContext appContext = 
  new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("your config path"); // /WEB_INF/...
```

It's better not to set your configs in the resource path [If its your external resource path]!
because it can access with clients!